# Looping with dplyr on each row of dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(var1=c(10,20,30,40,50), var2=c(rep(0.3,5)), BYGROUP_OBSNUM=c(0:4))

var1 var2 BYGROUP_OBSNUM
10   0.3          0
20   0.3          1
30   0.3          2
40   0.3          3
50   0.3          4
```

I need to perform calculations for each row using dplyr as my real dataframe is really huge and dplyr is very efficient.

What I want:

```
var1    var2    BYGROUP_OBSNUM  VAR1_NEW
10       0.3       0              10
20       0.3       1              23
30       0.3       2              36.9
40       0.3       3              51.07
50       0.3       4              65.321
```

How is this achieved:

```
var1    var2    BYGROUP_OBSNUM  VAR1_NEW    
10       0.3         0           10
20       0.3         1           20+10*0.3
30       0.3         2           30+20*0.3+10*0.3^2
40       0.3         3           40+30*0.3+20*0.3^2+10*0.3^3
50       0.3         4           50+40*0.3+30*0.3^2+20*0.3^3+10*0.3^4
```

Therefore for each row the formula is:

```
 var1[i]+lag(var1,1)*var2^1+lag(var1,2)*var2^2 +....
```

till the lag(var1) reaches the row where BYGROUP_OBSNUM is 0

What I have achieved till now:

```
df1<-df %>%
   mutate(var3=ifelse ((!(var2==0) | (!(BYGROUP_OBSNUM==0))),  var2, 0)) %>%
    rowwise()%>%
     ungroup() %>%
      mutate(var1_new=var1+lag(var1,1)*var2)
```

I need to change the last line such that the formula takes the lag from lag(var1,1) till lag(var1,BYGROUP_OBSNUM) for each row and power of var2 also increases from 1 to BYGROUP_OBSNUM. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm guesing that `ungroup()` cancels the `rowwise()`. So that's not doing anything.

Comment: Also, it seems [ungroup() strips off tbl_df class of a rowwise_df](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/936).

Comment: yes rowwise is useless..df1<-df %>%
   mutate(var3=ifelse ((!(var2==0) | (!(BYGROUP_OBSNUM==0))),  var2, 0)) %>%    
      mutate(var1_new=var1+lag(var1,1)*var2)

Comment: Not sure what your grouping is, but in base R you could do something like `with(df, sapply(seq_along(var1), function(i) sum(var1[seq_len(i-1)]*0.3^(rev(seq_len(i-1))))) + var1)`

Comment: This helps but only for small datasets. It takes a long time on a dataset of even 1 mil rows. There are some categorical variables used for grouping on the basis of which BYGROUP_OBSNUM col is made.

Comment: I changed the code to df1<-df %>%
  mutate(var3=ifelse ((!(var2==0) | (!(BYGROUP_OBSNUM==0))),  var2, 0)) %>%
  mutate(newvar=vapply(seq_along(BYGROUP_OBSNUM), function(i) sum(var1[seq_len(i-1)]*var3[seq_len(i-1)]^(rev(seq_len(i-1)))),FUN.VALUE = numeric(1)) + var1). This reduced the execution time significantly for 10k rows but takes a very long time for 100k rows. How do I optimize this even more?

Comment: do you need to do this by group? can you make your example more clear regarding the groupning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a custom function that can be used with dplyr to yield the results you are after. It works with the `group_by` function as well.

```
my.func <- function(x){
             mapply(function(v1,v2,n) {
               if(n == 1) {
                 as.numeric(v1[n])
               } else {
                 sum(v1, x[rev(seq(1:(n-1))),1] * v2 ^ seq(1:(n-1)))
               }
             }, x[,"var1"], x[,"var2"], seq(1:nrow(x)))
           }


df <- df %>% 
      # group_by(COLUMNS, TO, GROUP, BY) %>% 
      do(data.frame(., my.func(.))) %>%
      select(var1, var2, BYGROUP_OBSNUM, VAR1_NEW = my.func...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Made the final solution to--

```
df<-data.frame(var1=c(1:10),var2=c(rep(c(0,0.1),each=5)),BYG‌​ROUP_OBSNUM=c(0:4)) 

my.func <- function(x){mapply(function(v1,v2,v3,n) {
              if(v2==0 | v3==0){ as.numeric(v1) } 
              else { 
              sum(v1, x[rev(seq(1:(n-1))),1][1:v3] * v2 ^ seq(1:(n-1))[1:v3]) } },
             x[,"var1"], x[,"var2"], x[,"BYGROUP_OBSNUM"],seq(1:nrow(x))) 
            }

df1 <- df %>%   
         do(data.frame(., my.func(.))) %>% 
          mutate(VAR1_NEW = my.func...)%>% 
           select(-my.func...)
```

completed 100k rows in 1.42 mins! This function helped a lot! Thanks!